# Angular 2 routing hide selector when navigate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, routes

In my app component html, I have a selector  and router-outlet. When I try to navigate by clicking on a link, the selector  is still there. How can I hide the selector? Only router-outlet should be displaying.

app.component.html

```
<nav>
<a [routerLink]="['/heroes']">Click here</a>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet> <--  Display the content here 

<feed></feed> <--- feed component selector
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
selector: "app",
templateUrl: "app/app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

ngOnInit() {
}}
```

app.routing.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HeroComponent } from "./components/hero/hero.component";
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'heroes', component: HeroComponent}
];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

export const routingComponents = [HeroComponent];
```

Index.html

```
<app>Loading...</app>
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depends on your aim, do you want to remove all the content from the dom when the route changes?

if yes you should put the `router-outlet` in your app-component.

now it's behaving as expected, angular is rendering the view content of `HeroComponent` inside the `router-outlet` tag keeping any "extra" tag in the page

if you want to remove only the feed component from your view you can do like so:

```
 //take a reference to the current active route
 constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) {
   this.activeRoute = route.snapshot.url;

 }

<feed *ngIf="activeRoute !== '/heroes''"></feed>
```

Comment: I can also use someting like this *ngIf="router.url.includes('/')" with this, it should only render feed component, only if you are in main page or root page..